# What to do about error message about extra \else in greek.ldf?

Tags: errors, babel, greek

I get this error since I upgraded to texlive 2013:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua)))
! Extra \else.
l.74 \else

?
```

Posting this question directly in case someone has an easy answer. In the mean time I am trying to come up with a minimal example that gives me this error.

---

EDIT:

This:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}

    \usepackage[greek, english]{babel}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

gives:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013061817 (rev 4627) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-greek/greek.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def))
! Extra \else.
l.74 \else

?
```

So it seems to be `babel` somehow?

Comment: looks like this that @egreg just reported http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=babel/4360

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, the file being read is `greek.ldf` and so the problem is exactly what I reported. For the moment one has to comment out the `\fi` on line 73 in `greek.ldf`.

Comment: A message about this has also appeared on the TeX Live list: http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-September/034142.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug to be solved by a package update

Comment: It seems to me that this problem has been solved with the latest TL updates.